Cannot replace "U+FFFE" using Oracle SQL (OTBI Data Model)
I have this data "my shortterm objective" but when I tried replacing the "U+FFFE" with ' ', it does not work and I am still getting the same error.

I have tried these:

REPLACE(my_column, CHR(65534), ' ')
TRANSLATE(my_column, CHR(65534), ' ')
REGEXP_REPLACE(my_column, '[\x{FFFE}]', ' ')
REGEXP_REPLACE(my_column, '[^[:print:]]', ' ')


U+FFFE is explicitly defined as "noncharacter", thus it could be difficult to express it in regular expression. See https://www.unicode.org/faq/private_use.html#nonchar1

You can specify 0xFFFE as a unicode character point with u'\fffe':
create table my_table(my_column nvarchar2(50))

insert into my_table(my_column) values (unistr('my short\fffeterm objective'));

select dump(my_column, 1016) from my_table




DUMP(MY_COLUMN,1016)




Typ=1 Len=46 CharacterSet=AL16UTF16: 0,6d,0,79,0,20,0,73,0,68,0,6f,0,72,0,74,ff,fe,0,74,0,65,0,72,0,6d,0,20,0,6f,0,62,0,6a,0,65,0,63,0,74,0,69,0,76,0,65



select REPLACE(my_column, u'\fffe', ' '), dump(REPLACE(my_column, u'\fffe', ' '), 1016)
from my_table




REPLACE(MY_COLUMN,U'\FFFE','')
DUMP(REPLACE(MY_COLUMN,U'\FFFE',''),1016)




my short term objective
Typ=1 Len=46 CharacterSet=AL16UTF16: 0,6d,0,79,0,20,0,73,0,68,0,6f,0,72,0,74,0,20,0,74,0,65,0,72,0,6d,0,20,0,6f,0,62,0,6a,0,65,0,63,0,74,0,69,0,76,0,65



fiddle
However, FFFE is not a valid Unicode character, so it may be that whatever is showing you your current output is substituting something it can't display with that, and it isn't really in your string. Possibly you have a character set mismatch somewhere. Use dump() to see what you really have, and if that doesn't show ff,ee (I would guess it maybe has some type of dash?) then verify the character sets at each level..

Use UNISTR to generate the character:
SELECT REPLACE(data, UNISTR('\FFFE'), ' ') AS data
FROM   table_name;

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (data) AS
SELECT TO_CHAR(UNISTR('my short\FFFEterm objective')) FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



DATA




my short term objective



fiddle
